# SSL сертификат в связке apache nginx

Tags: apache, nginx, ssl

здравствуйте, если мой веб сервер использует связку nginx как front end apache, то SSL сертификат  нужно устанавливать на какой из них? SSL ключ от CloudFlare

Answer (score 4):

Поскольку nginx стоит на фронте, на него и ставьте:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name site.ru www.site.ru;
        rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;
}
server {
        listen     443 ssl http2;
        ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/site.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/site.key;

        server_name site.ru www.site.ru;

        // ну и так далее...

}
```